# 27 and 37 as repeating decimals

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

This is interesting... numbers 27 and 37, when you divide 10 by one of them, you have the other as a repeating decimal. Is there a name for this?

$$\begin{eqnarray}
    10 / 27 &=& 0.370370370370\ldots\\
    10 / 37 &=& 0.270270270270\ldots
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: The reason it works is 27*37=999.  That is, the property you describe of pairs of 2 digit 
integers m, n is equivalent to m*n=999.  As there are no other such factorisations of 999 (as a product of a pair of 2-digit integers) there may not have a been a reason to give it a name.

Comment: The same sort of thing would happen with any pair of $k$-digit numbers whose product is one less than a power of $10$, although you might have to adjust the power of $10$ in the numerator to kill the leading zeros.

Comment: Note the closely related phenomenon that $1/4=0.25, 1/25=0.04$. Many similar examples exist.

Comment: $27\times 37 = 999$ is interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an excellent thing to notice.  Congratulations!

As far as I know there is no name for this specific phenomenon.  To see why it happens, start with the observation that $$\frac1{999} = 0.001001001\ldots.$$

Then:  $$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{27}{999} & = & 0.027027027\ldots \\
\frac{37}{999} & = & 0.037037037\ldots \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Since $27\cdot 37 = 999$, the fractions on the left simplify to $\frac1{37}$ and $\frac1{27}$, respectively, and we have your observation.

We can observe the same thing happening with $3\cdot 333 = 999$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{3}{999} & = & \frac1{333} & = & 0.003003003\ldots \\
\frac{333}{999} & = & \frac13 & = & 0.333333333\ldots \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

or similarly, since $369\cdot 271 = 99999$ and $\frac1{99999} = 0.00001\;00001\;00001\ldots$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{271}{99999} & = & \frac1{369} & = & 0.00271\;00271\;00271\ldots \\
\frac{369}{99999} & = & \frac1{271} & = & 0.00369\;00369\;00369\ldots \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

---

The reason that $\frac1{999} = 0.001001001\ldots$ is because $0.001001001\ldots$ can be considered to be the sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series): $$\frac1{1000} + 
\left(\frac1{1000}\right)^2 +
\left(\frac1{1000}\right)^3 + \ldots.$$

When the sum of a series $x+x^2+x^3 \ldots$ exists, it is always $$\frac x{1-x}.$$  In this case we have $x=\frac1{1000}$, so the sum is $$\frac{\frac1{1000}}{1-\frac1{1000}} = \frac1{999}.$$  Other repeating decimals can be handled similarly.